# BeSimple Soap Library

Tags: php, soap, wshttpbinding

Does anyone have experience using the "BeSimple Soap Library"?

I'm looking for a php client to consume a ws-* soap service - and I have yet to find one. I am wondering if this will work for all ws-* features. There's very little by means of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It works with some of the WS-Security and WS-SecurityPolicy which is just tricky to do with the stock SoapClient class. Also it supports better determined namespacing, which is also problematic with some broken SOAP servers.

nuSoap and ZF2 SoapClient are ok, but BeSimple is more flexible in architectural PoV.

Answer (score 0):

The usual SOAP client in PHP would be the `SoapClient` class. See [documentation](http://de3.php.net/SoapClient). It works reasonably well, but is also not documentat that well.

Another alternative would be [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).